# How to add map position(lat ,lng) to database by 3 types (Numeric,geomatry, geohash)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I want to print lat-long by text and display in map types (Geomatry,numeric...).
and save the map position (lat-long) into database.

Comment: i tried to get lat-long position at current location,but i don't know to create geomatry type in map.

Comment: Just sow us the code which you have tried.

Comment: This is Jquery GPS code : [link](https://gyazo.com/e835189363c97e5720eb09aeb6dd147f)

Comment: What database engine? I assume MySQL?

Comment: Yes , I use mysql (PHPmyadmin)